# Está difundido a cultura de "Essa já tem resposta"?

Tags: debate

Provavelmente o título não deixará explícito o que quero dizer, e por isso tentarei explicar o mais breve possível. De antemão, não possuo números e pode parecer apenas achismo, porém gostaria de compartilhar com vocês o meu pensamento:

De modo geral, não há apenas uma maneira de fazer quaisquer tarefas, independente do que seja. Vejo com uma certa frequência, que as questões possuem apenas uma resposta, sei que se foi o suficiente para o AP, ótimo que ajudou!

Porém me indago se a comunidade, ao ver uma questão com uma resposta já efetuada, fica com receio ou mesmo preguiça de responder, com um método diferente ou uma maneira não usual de solucionar aquele problema.

Comment: Se tem um método diferente basta postar na pergunta que será usada para marcar como [dup], afinal se você olhar para as perguntas com respostas "aceita" irá notar que ainda é possivel responder. Lembre-se uma resposta aceita não significa a melhor.

Comment: Sim, eu particularmente respondo mesmo se já houver respostas anteriores e/ou aceitas, mas em geral não vejo isso na comunidade.

Comment: vejo direto por parte de quem entende o quanto não marcar dup é ruim

Comment: Não estou falando de ti, é que tem 5 usuários o qual já orientei umas 3 vezes cada e eles insistem duplicar as respostas.

Comment: Acredito eu que quando o AP marca uma resposta como aceita, desincentiva alguns que estariam dispostos a ajudar, mas não o fazem por já haver uma solução, claro, nem todos devem pensar assim, mas pode ser uma causa.

Comment: Verdade, as vezes é uma pequena diferença que a pessoa desconsidera na hora de avaliar como duplicada e é onde está a principal dúvida do que perguntou! Os casos podem ser parecidos, mas raramente é a mesma coisa!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Como assim duplicar respostas?

Comment: @leo_ap pensa que uma pergunta é diferente de outra... Então pensa que nessa pergunta diferente a resposta serve para as duas perguntas... Ou seja se uma resposta resolve o problema, mesmo estando em outra pergunta o melhor á marcar como duplicata, se não resolve é porque não é dup... O que acontece é que muitas vezes os caras fazem respostas novas em perguntas novas o qual já existe resposta em outra pergunta e o melhor seria pesquisar se já não existe uma resposta que resolve o problema. Para mais detalhes http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5719/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ah sim, entendi agora. Achei que as pessoas estavam duplicando respostas de outras pessoas em uma mesma pergunta. Obrigado por me apresentar esse link.

Answer (score 16):

É possível, é uma pena. Eu acho que é sempre bom ter respostas diversas e sinto falta mais disso.

Claro que não faz sentido dar outra resposta idêntica ou quase idêntica, precisa acrescentar algo mais ou pelo menos ser com outras palavras. Isso é algo importante, uma pessoa pode não entender uma resposta e entender a outra escrita diferente, mesmo que o conteúdo seja idêntico (não a forma).

Uma coisa que eu acho que atrapalha um pouco é que se uma resposta é dada antes ela tende a receber votos porque já teve votos anteriormente. Mais ainda se é aceita. Isso desestimula um pouco outras respostas. Muitas vezes a nova resposta é melhor, mas não recebe o devido crédito porque não pegou o *hot time* da pergunta.

Vez ou outra acontece da pessoa não se importar e postar mesmo tendo algo que já responde bem. Eu sempre faço isto quando tenho algo que realmente acrescente algo útil de conteúdo, ou forma.

É uma pena, mas eu gostaria que cada pergunta tivesse pelo menos 3 respostas. Quem sabe algumas pessoas se sensibilizam com essa postagem e comecem fazer mais.

Comment: O teu terceiro paragrafo diz tudo.

Answer (score 2):

Realmente isso pode estar acontecendo, como já foi dito pelo [bigown](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/101/bigown), é sempre bom termos mais de uma resposta para as perguntas.

Acredito que precisamos mudar um pouco nosso conceito sobre qual é o real objetivo do SOpt. O SOpt é acima de tudo um portal onde podemos não somente buscar ajuda da comunidade, como também contribuir para a comunidade.

Por várias vezes, respondi uma questão e logo abaixo surgiram outras respostas, que além de dar uma visão mais ampla para o assunto, geraram uma discussão sadia que com certeza ajudará inúmeras pessoas.

Um exemplo é esta [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93717/porque-usar-o-bloco-using-no-asp-net-mvc/93723#93723), nela vemos um grande esforço dos usuários em, antes de qualquer coisa mostrar um caminho a se seguir para a pessoa que fez a pergunta. Além disso esse material com certeza será de grande utilidade para quem tiver a mesma dúvida.

Não podemos ser egoístas ao ponto de não compartilhar o nosso conhecimento só porque o problema discutido já foi sanado, devemos entender que tudo que escrevemos fica documentado e pode auxiliar outras pessoas futuramente.

Comment: É mais ou menos isso, mas não sei se tem a ver com egoísmo.

Comment: Foi força de expressão, digo egoísmo, voltado àquele pensamento de segurar a informação para si e não compartilhar o seu conhecimento.

Comment: Justamente, eu acho que não é esse o motivo das pessoas não postarem novas respostas porque já existe uma resposta. Até tem gente que faz isso, mas em geral a pessoa nem participa do site.